# Cannot send or retrieve extras using startactivityforresult

Tags: android, android-intent

Activity myActivity1:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, myActivity2.class);
i.putExtra("type", type);
if(type == 1)
{
    i.putExtra("namesArray", myArray);
}
startActivityForResult(i, 1);
```

Activity myActivity2:

```
//inside onResume()
if(getIntent().hasExtra("type"))
{
    Log.i(tag, "Has extra");
}
else
{
    Log.i(tag, "No extra type");
}
```

I always get `"No extra type"` why ?

Comment: Does it work if you put the code in `myActivity2` in `onCreate`?

Comment: @Szymon no it does not. (onResume runs after onCreate, so no effect in this situation)

Comment: Can you post more code of myActivity2?

Comment: I just did a small project with these 2 activities (A starts B with `startActivityForResult`) and I getting true result.

Comment: @Szymon yes. but I think it would be pointless.

Comment: it may sound silly but could you try Intent i = new Intent(myActivity1.this, myActivity2.class);   and if(getParent().getIntent().hasExtra("type"))
{
    Log.i(tag, "Has extra");
}
else
{
    Log.i(tag, "No extra type");
}

Comment: @DeepakSamuelRajan I got a java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: does using bundle change anything ?

Comment: parent for Activity B is null let it be same with getIntent().hasExtra("type")  only change Intent i = new Intent(myActivity1.this, myActivity2.class); in myActivity1 sorry for number of trials because ur code works fine for me

Comment: if ur this.getIntent().getExtras(); is coming as null always try putting i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); in myActivity1

Comment: I am also having no problem getting the skeleton code you've listed to work as expected. I.e., I am getting "Has extra." I think you're going to have to post more of your code; something's missing.

Answer (score 1):

If myActivity2 was created previously before receiving the intent, it's possible that `getIntent()` is returning the original intent that created the activity in the first place, which probably didn't have any extras set.

Try the following to refresh the intent:

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    setIntent(intent);
}
```

Comment: what you said makes perfect sense. However, in my case, myActivity2 is starting only from myActivity1 through out the whole app, so the technical possibility of myActivity2 starting at a prior stage without an extra intent is almost zero. Regardless, I add the above overridden method, but nothing happened. - IMO, this is a simple case, and there is not much to look for, except that getIntent() is returning an old intent without the extras... the question is, why ?